# Temporary variable in SQL Statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, select, sql-order-by

I have an function defined in SQL that computes the Levenshtein distance between two given strings.

Currently I call this function in a manner similar to the one below:

```
SELECT * FROM movies M WHERE levenshtein ( M.title, "Foobar" ) < 5;
```

I would like to use order the results in ascending order of the levenshtein distance, but do not know the proper way to do so.

Is there a way to do this or will I have to do it in a different manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`levenshtein()` is an expensive function. If performance is at all relevant, you might want to avoid to call it twice. Use a sub-select for that. (In other RDBMS' you might use a CTE, but MySQL doesn't have that.)

Run a test to see which performs better.

```
SELECT some_col
FROM   (SELECT some_col, levenshtein(title, 'Foobar') AS levi FROM movies) AS m
WHERE  levi < 5
ORDER  BY levi;
```

BTW, you didn't want to put the *table alias* in the SELECT list like in your example, did you?

Comment: Sorry about that mistake! I fixed it.

Thank you for showing this!

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY levenshtein ( M.title, "Foobar" )
```

Comment: I was thinking about this, but does this not call the function twice (it is already expensive, so I don't think I should call it twice)? Or does it optimize?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just reuse the function in the order by clause like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM movies M
WHERE levenshtein ( M.title, "Foobar" ) < 5
ORDER BY levenshtein ( M.title, "Foobar" );
```

The other option, is to output the results of all records, with the addition of a column for your function call, to a temporary table and then select from that using the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clause on the column in question.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but does this not call the function twice (it is already expensive, so I don't think I should call it twice)? Or does it optimize?

Comment: @Kaushik I'm not entirely sure. If you do it the second way though (using a temporary table), it would only be called once.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for similar answers, I have some practical experience with the same kind of issue.

While it works quite well, the problem with...

```
ORDER BY levenshtein ( M.title, "Foobar" )
```

...is not that it performs the function twice (from testing against a 500,000 row table, I don't believe it does), but that the query uses filesort to perform the ORDER BY. As you may be aware, incorporating the ORDERed columns in the WHERE clause removes the need for filesort. The problem is that the ORDERed values are not columns and don't work as pure column references would.